# In Notion, how to have different percentages of completion for the subprojects of a project?

Tags: notion

In Notion, I created a Completion column for a project named My Project, with two sub projects. Then, I set a task for each project and put their status to Done. Here is what I obtain:

[image]

So, the Completion for My Project is empty, I would like it to be 100%. Also, is it possible to set My Subproject 1 and 2 with different weights ? (e.g. Subproject 1 reprensents 40% whereas Subproject 2 represents 60% of the total project.)

Thanks

p.s: I tried to do something with a Formula column, but it's not very well [documented](https://listekconsulting.notion.site/Notion-Formulas-30d8d88656534222949d7210eccfa608#b4a77e3a8bca4f038a4d61d6af8cd409)